# Function returns incorrect False (only at higher values)

Tags: python, limits

At higher input values my `checkInputFile()` function will return false, even when the input is a legal value. This only really becomes a problem with values greater than 400, but I want to be able to use numbers up to 10,000.

I've attached the a module used for getting user input, as well as the text files used to generate the insults.

```
import random
from getNum import *

def main() :
    random.seed()
    allWords = loadInsults()
    print("One insult: ", end="")
    print(generateInsult(allWords))
    insults = generateInsults(allWords)
    displaySomeInsults(insults)
    saveInsults(insults)
    if checkInsultsFile() :
        print("\n1000 insults properly saved. They are unique and in order.")
    else :
        print("\nThe insults are not properly generated or saved!")

# Using all possible arguments and prompting the user for the number of insults.
    allWords = loadInsults("word1.txt", "word2.txt", "word3.txt")
    numInsults = getNumInsults()
    insults = generateInsults(allWords, numInsults)
    displaySomeInsults(insults)
    saveInsults(insults, "Insults.txt")
    if checkInsultsFile(numInsults, "Insults.txt") :
        print("\n" + str(numInsults) + " insults properly saved. They are unique and in order.")
    else :
        print("\nThe insults are not properly generated or saved!")

# Write your functions here:

def readFiles(fileName):
    inFile = open(fileName, "r")
    fileContentsList = []
    for line in inFile:
        fileContentsList.append(line.rstrip())
    inFile.close()
    return fileContentsList

def loadInsults(word1="word1.txt", word2="word2.txt", word3="word3.txt"):
    return readFiles(word1), readFiles(word2), readFiles(word3)

def generateInsult(allWords):
    return "thou " + random.choice(allWords[0]) + " " + random.choice(allWords[1]) \
           + " " + random.choice(allWords[2]) + "!"

def generateInsults(allWords, numInsults=100):
    insultList = []
    while len(insultList) < numInsults:

        insultList.append(generateInsult(allWords))
    insults = list(set(insultList))
    return insults

def displaySomeInsults(insults):
    insults.sort()
    print("Some insults:")
    for i in insults[0 : 10]:
        print(i)
    print(". \n<snip>\n.")
    for i in insults[-11 : -1]:
        print(i)

def saveInsults(insults, filename="Insults.txt"):
    if 100 <= len(insults) <= 10000:
        outFile = open(filename, "w")
        for line in insults:
            outFile.write(line + "\n")
        outFile.close()

def checkInsultsFile(numInsults=100, filename="Insults.txt"):
        inFile = open(filename, "r")
        newList = []
        for line in inFile:
            newList.append(line.rstrip())
        inFile.close()
        for i in range(1, len(newList)):
            if newList[i] < newList[i-1]:
                print("Not all insults are in order")
                return False
            elif newList[i] == newList[i-1]:
                print("Not all insults are unique")
                return False
        if len(newList) != numInsults:
            print("Wrong number of insults.")
            return False
        return True

def getNumInsults():
    numInsults = getNum("\nEnter a number between 100 and 10,000: ", 100, 10000)
    return numInsults

main()
```

Comment: not sure how to attach the text files or other module!

Comment: In all cases where `checkInsultsFile()` returns False, it also prints an error message.  What message is it printing?  That really should lead you right to the cause.

Comment: When it returns false, which message does it print out? Also, can you print out the value of newList and numInsults just before it returns false? If you do that, you may be able to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may know what is happening, you are creating a set of insults out of your list which will remove any duplicates. The more insults you generate, the more likely there will be a duplicate which will cause your set of insults to be smaller than numInsults.

This line will remove duplicates: `insults = list(set(insultList))`

Causing the length of the insults list to be smaller than numInsults.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for my bad question etiquette, this is my first time posting on here!!